# i wrote "r" at the beganing of the path i work but i can only read what should i do to be able to write in the file

Tags: python

```
mazen_file=open(r"C:\Users\uscs\Desktop\mazen" )
mazen_file.write("gamed nek")
mazen_file.close()
```

i got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uscs\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\حديد المصرين.py", line 2, in <module>
    mazen_file.write("gamed nek")
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

I tried to write in the file but I could not

Comment: Files are opened for reading by default.  Give `"w"` as a second parameter to `open()` to get writing mode.

Answer (score 0):

The `r` before the string has nothing to do with reading. It stands for raw string, which means python ignores special characters and thus you can use `\` instead of `\\`. In order to open a file for writing, you need to specify the mode like this : `mazen_file=open(r"C:\Users\uscs\Desktop\mazen", 'w')` where `w` is the mode for opening the file. If you want to explore other modes, check [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).